# How to localize chrono days?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I have a code https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cde949e0a59445ee9beb01964a3ab903

```
use chrono::Datelike;
use chrono::Duration;
use chrono::Local;

fn main() {
    let now = Local::now();
    println!("######################################");
    for day in 0..31 {
        println!(
            "{}",
            (now + Duration::days(7 - now.weekday().num_days_from_monday() as i64 + day))
                .format("%Y-%m-%d %A")
        );
        println!("\ntest\n\n########################");
    }
}
```

**Q:** Where I need the weekdays to be in ex.: "HU" language and not in the English "Monday, Tuesday", etc.

I already tried based on https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/ the ", Locale::hu_HU)" but always failed so far, can you pls help on this?

Comment: One workaround is to use the ICU calender instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the feature `unstable-locales` for this. See [here](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/index.html?search=#formatting-and-parsing) for the usage of  `format_localized`.

Comment: I tried, thanks! https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f30ea7d0e0b7e5f1ee852d7b53f93aee so far it gaved 

4 | use chrono::unstable-locales;
  |                     ^ expected one of `::`, `;`, or `as`

Comment: @jim7475 Did you put `chrono { version = "0.4", features = ["unstable-locales"]` into your `Cargo.toml`? I think that's what's needed, not `use chrono::unstable-locales;` in `main.rs`.